# How to specify parameter from multiple optional parameters

Tags: c#, .net, optional-parameters

I have a method that takes one dynamically typed (probably not relevant) parameter and multiple optional parameters of more than one type.  Is there any way to specify which parameters you are passing?

With this code I am getting compiler errors (below), and I wold like not to have to write overloads or rewrite the function with multiple orders for the optional parameters.

- Error 2 Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'bool'
- Error 1 The best overloaded method match for  Index(int, bool,
  bool, string)'  has some invalid arguments

Code:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    Index<int>(Id, false,"test"); //compiler error 
}

private void Index<T>(T o, bool flush = false, bool userDispose = true, string starter = "stop")
{

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mark optional parameters with the name followed by a double point. In your example:

```
public void DoSomeWork()
{
    Index<int>(Id, false, starter: "test");
}
```

This means that `Id` and `false` names the first two parameters `o` and `flush`, the third parameter `userDispose` is not set and the parameter `starter` is set with `test`.

For more informations about named and optional parameters, have a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Comment: Interresting, I didn't know that !

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for (will mark as answer as soon as it lets me).

Answer (score 3):

Use [named arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), which is one of the great features of C#.

```
 Index<int>(Id, flush: false, starter: "test");
```